# Passing a callback with more arguments than it should have

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise, arguments

I have the following function:

```
function getRandomTweetFromLocation(geocode) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var count = 50;
        T.get('search/tweets', {
            q: geocode,
            count: count
        }, function (err, data, response) {
```

instead of passing that anonymous function as a callback, I wanted to pass another function that would receive `err, data, response`, but it also needs to receive `resolve, reject` in order to resolve the promise. I've written the function like this:

```
function chooseAGoodTweet(err, data, response, resolve, reject) {
```

but if I pass its name as the callback, it'll only receive `err, data, response`. Is there a way to pass it as a callback but make `resolve` and `reject` go together?

Comment: You'd have to use a wrapper function in the original callback, what have you tried?

Comment: @Goliadkin I thought of it but the wrapper would receive only err, data, response. How to do the rest???

Comment: can you please show more code - you mention passing an anonymous function as callback, but there is no such function.  In any event you can probably achieve what you want via promise chaining.

Comment: @Alnitak it's the function (err, data, response) {

Comment: OK, albeit still not entirely clear because you haven't shown your use case for passing that function as a reference rather than declaring it inline.   Either way, if you're using Promises, it's almost never necessary to also pass callbacks.    Your `getRandomTweetFromLocation` function should be resolving (or rejecting) itself and passing either the `data` or the `err` values, and then you use the promise chain to decide the next action.

Comment: (or put another way, having access to the resolve and reject functions from outside the scope of the `new Promise` callback is almost certainly an anti-pattern)

Comment: I think you should have a deeper look at promises...

Comment: @Jonasw what I'm going wrong with promises?

Comment: In my opinion it doesnt make sense to pass resolve and reject in any way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you need to wrap just the `T.get()` in a promise wrapper and then use that promise wrapper to get the results of the function.

Secondly, promises ONLY ever resolve with a single argument so if you want to pass more than one argument to them, you put those multiple arguments into an object and resolve with the object.  Here's a way you could do that:

```
// make promise-returning version of T.get()
function tGetAsync(geocode, cnt) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        T.get('search/tweets', {q: geocode, count: cnt}, function (err, data, response) {   
            if (err) return reject(err);
            // put multiple results into an object and resolve with that single object
            resolve({data: data, response: response});
        });
    });
}
```

The, you can use that like this:

```
 tGetAsync(someGeoCode, someCnt).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.data);
    console.log(result.response);
 }).catch(function(err) {
    console.err(err);
 });
```

You don't show what `chooseAGoodTweet()` is supposed to do, but it can use `tGetAsync()` like this:

```
function chooseAGoodTweet(geocode) {
    return tGetAsync(geoCode, 50).then(function(result) {
        // do some processing of result.data or result.response
        // and return a value here
        return someTweet;
    });
}
```

Then, you would use it as:

```
chooseAGoodTweet(someGeoCode).then(function(tweet) {
    // process chosen tweet here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

> Is there a way to pass it as a callback but make resolve and reject go together?

You can't change what a callback will be passed from outside the function that calls the callback.  There is simply no way to do that.  You can either edit the function that calls the callback to change what it passes to the callback or you can insert a stub callback that gets the expected callback arguments and then adds some more to call your callback.

But, in this case, it appears you're mostly just misunderstanding how promises work so you need to get that right first and then you will have the proper arguments.

Comment: I don't want to resolve err, data, response. The funciton chooseAGoodTweet uses err, data, response to choose only one tweet from data and resolve it

Comment: I understand that resolve just resolves one thing, can't use more than once, and the intention was to dissect err, data, response and return just one tweet, one time, from that

Comment: @Gatonito - I added some more info to my answer.  You don't show anything about what you want `chooseAGoodTweet()` to actually do, but I did show how it calls and uses `tGetAsync()`.  Note: it is considered a good design pattern when adding promises to a non-promise API to add the promise at the lowest level and then use the promise implementation in the your own implementation and NOT add any application specific logic to the layer where you are promisifying.  That's why I made `tGetAsync()` that only adds the promise.  You then implement your app-specific logic in `chooseAGoodTweet()`.